# when does rails looks for Index method and when for show method in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-routing

I'm new to Rails and I have been following a tutorial.

I have been fiddling around with routes.rb and now in total confusion about when it looks for show method and when for index method if not explicitly mentioned?

Comment: If you're loading page `/posts`, then it's `index`. If the page is `/posts/123`, then it's `show` (is id present in the url or not)

Comment: Even when I did not have have id in the URL it was looking for show method. I have created the model with resources.

Comment: "it was looking for show method" - this shouldn't happen. It means, you messed up _somewhere_.

Answer (score 14):

Routes are simply like regexes on steroids. They have priority in the order they are defined and match the request method, URI and any other constraints that you have added.

```
 get '/posts', to: 'posts#index'
 get '/posts/:id', to: 'posts#show'
```

The key difference to the routes above is that the regular expression which the path of request uri must match is different. `'/posts/:id'` includes a named segment which would match:

```
GET /posts/11
GET /posts/gobligook
```

But not:

```
GET /posts
GET /posts/1/foo
GET /posts/foo/bar
```

The full conventional set of CRUD verbs are:

```ruby
get    '/posts',          to: 'posts#index'   # all posts
get    '/posts/new',      to: 'posts#new'     # form to create a post
post   '/posts',          to: 'posts#create'  # create a post from a form submission
get    '/posts/:id',      to: 'posts#show'    # show a single post
get    '/posts/:id/edit', to: 'posts#edit'    # form to edit a post
put    '/posts/:id',      to: 'posts#update'  # for legacy compatibility 
patch  '/posts/:id',      to: 'posts#update'  # update a post from a form submission
delete '/posts/:id',      to: 'posts#destroy' # delete a post
```

In Rails flavor REST the action is implicitly derived from the path and method.
Only the **new** and **edit** methods which are used to render forms actually explicitly add the action in the path - which is because they act on a collection or a member of a collection.

Note that the `'/posts/new'` route must be declared before `get '/posts/:id'` or the show route would match the request first (routes have priority in the order they are defined). This does not apply to `get '/posts/:id/edit'` since the pattern is different.

Of course typing out all those routes is really tedious so rails provides the [`resources` macro](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default) that does this for you:

```
resources :posts
```

Comment: Another important thing to remember is that routes don't give a damn about your controllers or models. They just try to match the incoming request and if the controller does not really exist its not their problem.

Answer (score 6):

Both index and show are GET method, but the difference is index is **collection type** and show is **member type**. Which means index does not expect any parameter in the url, but show expects id param in the url.

```
EX:
Index: /posts
Show: /posts/:id
```

Comment: I entered the "/posts/new" (new is the action method) in the URL and it took new as id because new was not existing in the controller yet?

Comment: Have you added route for "new" action?

Comment: no I guess. If I had added the route for new action, it would ask for method "new", right?

Answer (score 5):

Rails chose [`convention over configuration`](http://rubyonrails.org/doctrine/#convention-over-configuration). That's why the actions are not explicitly named.

Here is the complete list of the expected actions for a given controller: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions

[image: crud-verbs-and-actions]